# How to add image dimensions in an image being added via regex

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

Here is a piece of PHP code from a WordPress plugin that adds an image into the content by using preg_replace. The problem is that the added image has no dimensions specified and as this image is added multiple times on every page, it slows down page rendering (to a very small extent). Now, the question is:

**How to add width = "1" and height= "1" into the final HTML of the image being added via the below mentioned PHP regex?**

```
 // In case you want to change the placeholder image
        $placeholder_image = apply_filters( 'lazyload_images_placeholder_image', self::get_url( 'images/1x1.trans.gif' ) );


    // This is a pretty simple regex, but it works
        $content = preg_replace( '#<img([^>]+?)src=[\'"]?([^\'"\s>]+)[\'"]?([^>]*)>#', sprintf( '<img${1}src="%s" data-lazy-src="${2}"${3}><noscript><img${1}src="${2}"${3}></noscript>', $placeholder_image ), $content );
        return $content;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of them has dimensions set, You can simply add `width="1" height="1"` to img tag.

Like this:

```
$content = preg_replace( '#<img([^>]+?)src=[\'"]?([^\'"\s>]+)[\'"]?([^>]*?)(\/)?>#', sprintf( '<img${1}src="%s" data-lazy-src="${2}"${3} width="1" height="1" /><noscript><img${1}src="${2}"${3}></noscript>', $placeholder_image ), $content );
```

If added at the end of `<img>` tag it should't interfer even when oryginal image would have it set already.

Comment: Although it adds the height and the width attributes but I am getting these errors on W3C validator: 

A slash was not immediately followed by >.
…t="Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1"></noscript></a> ...... Duplicate attribute width.
…t="Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1"></noscript></a> ...... Duplicate attribute height.
…t="Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1"></noscript></a>

Comment: I've modified code, to handle this slash. Should work.

Comment: It still doesn't work as I am getting this error now: A slash was not immediately followed by >.…"Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1" /></noscript></a> ..... Duplicate attribute width.
…"Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1" /></noscript></a> .......... Duplicate attribute height.
…"Interesting Facts About Harry Potter" / width="1" height="1" /></noscript></a>

Comment: Sorry, during weekend I didn't have time to test it.
Another edit, now tested : )